# Declaring function within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have this jquery utility code that automatically adds a handler for events to any UI element as long as it has ID. So for example, if I have this element:

```
<button id="compute-bills">Compute</button>
```

instead of writing this to give it a `onClick` listener:

```
$(function() {
    $("#compute-bills").on("click", function() {
        // function body
    });
});
```

our team uses this instead:

```
var computeBillsOnClick = function() {
    // function body
}
```

Now, introducing my problem, I have this scenario:

```
<input type="hidden" class="geonameId" name="geonameId">
<input type="text" class="geonameLocation" name="geonameLocation" id="geoname-location">
...
<input type="hidden" class="geonameId" name="mondayGeonameId">
<input type="text" class="geonameLocation" name="mondayGeonameLocation" id="monday-geoname-location">
...
<input type="hidden" class="geonameId" name="tuesdayGeonameId">
<input type="text" class="geonameLocation" name="tuesdayGeonameLocation" id="tuesday-geoname-location">
...
<input type="hidden" class="geonameId" name="wednesdayGeonameId">
<input type="text" class="geonameLocation" name="wednesdayGeonameLocation" id="wednesday-geoname-location">
...
<input type="hidden" class="geonameId" name="thursdayGeonameId">
<input type="text" class="geonameLocation" name="thursdayGeonameLocation" id="thursday-geoname-location">
...
<input type="hidden" class="geonameId" name="fridayGeonameId">
<input type="text" class="geonameLocation" name="fridayGeonameLocation" id="friday-geoname-location">
<!-- Plus some 20-ish similar nodes-->
```

Every element of `.geonameLocation` class is actually an autocomplete field (that uses a separate plugin), that is when filled up, will set the value of the `.geonameId` that comes before that field. Using our shorthand notation, we assign the value of `.geonameId` like this:

```
var geonameLocationOnAutoComplete = function() {
    var geonameLocation = $("#geoname-location");
    var geonameId = geonameLocation.prev();

    // Do some magic
    // var id = ...

    geonameId.val(id);
};
//...
var fridayGeonameLocationOnAutoComplete = function() {
    var geonameLocation = $("#friday-geoname-location");
    var geonameId = geonameLocation.prev();

    // Do some magic
    // var id = ...

    geonameId.val(id);
};
```

So, instead of repeating the code, I instead thought of placing the declaration of the function in a loop:

```
var geonames = [
    "geoname-location",
    "monday-geoname-location",
    // ...
    "friday-geoname-location",
    // plus 20-ish other ID that implements the same callback.
];

for(var x = 0; x < geonames.length; x++) {
    var geonameLocation = $("#" + geonames[x]);
    var geonameId = geonameLocation.prev();

    window[geonames[x].toCamelCase() + "OnAutoComplete"] = function() {
        console.log(geonameLocation); // undefined
        console.log(geonameId); // undefined

        // Do some magic
        // var id = ...

        geonameId.val(id);
    };
}
```

The problem is that the `geonameLocation` and `geonameId` variables are undefined within the function body. Therefore, I cannot use them in the process I'm performing. I want to know the reason behind this and if I can use this approach of declaring a function within a loop.

**Edit:** I changed the event from `onBlur` to a custom event since my case is actually not a normal event and thus cannot use this code on accessing the triggering element:

```
var geonameLocation = $(e.target);
```

Comment: i never seen something like this:- `window[geonames[x].toCamelCase() + "Blur"] = function() {` can you please state what it's doing and pls add it's code too

Comment: they are just setting a global variable at that part

Answer (score 0):

I would instead do the following:

```
geonameBlur = function(name) {
  var geonameLocation = $('#' + name);
  var geonameId = geonameLocation.prev();
 ... do the needfull ...
}
```

then you could have:
`window["fridayGeonameLocationBlur"] = function() { geonameBlur('friday-geoname-location'); }` as the event